# Change in styleSheet

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

How to change in `QPushButton` only one item with `setStyleSheet`? The word "item" or "element" I mean "background-color", "border-color", "border-radius", and so on.
If you do so:

```
setStyleSheet("QPushButton {"
                  "background-color: blue;"
                  "}");
```

the remaining elements (`border-radius`, ...) will default. And I want to change only one of elements, the other do not touch. For example, I have `QPushButton` with stylesheet like so:

```
setStyleSheet("QPushButton {"
                      "background-color: blue;"
                      "border-radius: 5";
"}");
```

if I want to change `border-radius` this way:

```
setStyleSheet("QPushButton {"
                          "border-radius: 10";
    "}");
```

I also change `background-color` to default value, but I want to change only `border-radius` (other elements I do not change).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *melt by default*? Screenshots of what you want and what you're getting would also help a lot.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi I changed question

Answer (score 3):

From [Qt Style Sheets Examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html):

> If we want the property to apply only to one specific `QLineEdit`, we
>   can give it a name using `QObject::setObjectName()` and use an ID
>   Selector to refer to it:
>
> ```
> myDialog->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit#nameEdit { background-color: yellow }");
> ```

---

Always search through Qt's documentation first. It's one of the best I've seen.

Comment: sorry, the word "element" I mean "background-color", "border-color", "border-radius", ...

Comment: @Tapac You might try to make several style sheets (using string concatenation) and then change object names dynamically. Let me know about the result.